# Google account management

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am working with google gcp projects (say dialogflow) at work.
My team and I made google accounts with our work emails which we added to our GCP projects.
I noticed that once an email is deactivated, the google account associated with it remains and can access GCP projects. How can I maintain this relationship between my GCP project, google account and work email such that if the work email is deactivated then the associated google account also is deleted and thus their access to the GCP project also gets removed.

PS: Any way to maintain a parent-child google accounts such that one google account(parent) can deactivate children google accounts

Comment: A good answer requires more information. For example what email system are you using for work emails?

Answer (score 0):

In the Google Cloud Console, go to the Manage Billing Accounts page.

Select the name of the billing account you want to manage.

From the Billing navigation menu, click Account management.

On the Account management page, linked projects are listed under Projects linked to this billing account.

Comment: I am not sure how does this achieve the parent-child relationship or link email to google account in such a way that deactivation of email also deactivates google account

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean with "deactivate account" or where you are deactivating those accounts, also if all of those accounts are part of the same domain/organization or part of G Suite directory.

I guess that you mean that you add the accounts to the IAM roles section. The IAM API service does not read the status of external accounts (if that is the case) so the intended way to restrict access of accounts that you add to IAM is the same way, deleting those accounts from the IAM by yourself or your System Administrator.